# WPF вывод ответа из командной строки

Tags: c#, wpf, gui, cmd

Всем привет! Не выводится на экран ответ от командной строки при запуске JLink.exe,при нажатии кнопки "ReadMemory" ничего не происходит.
Но если после этого ввести команду "exit" выводятся все операции, произведенные в командной строке.
Как можно это исправить и почему это происходит?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Process jLinkProcess = new Process();
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        jLinkProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\SEGGER\JLink\JLink.exe");
        jLinkProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        jLinkProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        jLinkProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        jLinkProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        jLinkProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        jLinkProcess.OutputDataReceived += CmdProcess_OutputDataReceived;
        jLinkProcess.ErrorDataReceived += CmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
        jLinkProcess.Start();
        jLinkProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        jLinkProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("connect");
        jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("NRF52811_XXAA");
        jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("SWD");
        jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("4000");
    }

    private void CmdProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            TextBox2.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
            TextBox2.ScrollToEnd();
        });
    }

    private void CmdProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            TextBox2.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
            TextBox2.ScrollToEnd();
        });
    }

    private void TextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox textBox && e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(textBox.Text);
            textBox.Text = string.Empty;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void ReadMemory(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string mac = "mem 10000060,8";
        jLinkProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(mac);
    }
}
```

Comment: А если через cmd запустить? То есть как в исходном примере там, где вы этот код взяли.

Comment: @aepot. Точно так же получается, сообщения от командной строки выводятся. запускаю Jlink.exe ,вывода нет. Ввожу exit все появляется.
Мне кажется,что Jlink.exe блокирует командную строку .Мне кажется нужно запихнуть Process c Jlink в отдельный поток и также cmd поместить в отдельный поток,а затем обмениваться между ними данными.
Я правильно думаю? Просто в этой ещё совсем новичок.

Comment: Нет, не правильно, оно и так все в отдельном потоке. На уровне приложения ничего не блокируется.

Comment: Я понял в чем проблема. Приложение пишет в буфер, и пока буфер не заполнится, данные не приходят. Если приложение закрыть - буфер сбрасывается в консоль. Это не исправить, если вы не имеете доступа к исходникам приложения. Можно попробовать вызвать `jLinkProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Flush();`, например после отправки команды через несколько миллисекунд, но вряд-ли поможет, потому что проблема на стороне приложения, а не консоли.

Comment: Спасибо! То есть выходит GUI с таким приложением написать нельзя? Только вручную команды вводить через консоль?

Comment: Вы попробовали или сразу писать комментарий начали? Есть еще `jLinkProcess.StartInfo.EnableRaisingEvents = true;`, можете добавить к настройкам процесса. Сначала все попробуйте, потом сами сможете ответить на свой вопрос.

Comment: @aepot А если дело в буфере, то почему когда запускаю напрямую из командной строки все работает?